Is there a name for the text that shows up after executing each command line in a CLI?
for example in linux terminal I have
jurek@debian:~$ man help
No manual entry for help

I want to know how the second line is called
bc I want to ask an other question "How to copy this term (I'm looking for) to clipboard from CLI using key shortcut and then past it to search enginer or so.
Thank you

It's the standard output or standard error of the command, or both.

@choroba do you know how to scroll through linux terminal up and down using shortcuts or use cursor on text contents of it?

Which terminal app? Generally it's easier to do with the mouse

Depends on what terminal you use. Much easier with screen or tmux.

@choroba I think more precisely, the content themselve are "output (data)" or "error (messages)", while "standard output" and "standard error" refer to the "communication channels" (or often the respective file descriptor or associate device, i.e., the "endpoints").

@konto Not sure. Do the program you look up really comes with a man page? Also, shell builtin (such as help) will not have a man page. You can only e.g. help help or man bash.

@TomYan thank you this solved it
